# Good Scala introductory article/video to whet the appetite

Tags: scala

What are some good online articles or videos you've seen that would be most likely to get a developer interested in Scala?  I'm looking for an introduction that is brief & to the point that dives right into example code, and would leave a developer who does not know Scala wanting to learn more about it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/203968

Answer (score 6):

Try in this order:

[Pragmatic Real-World Scala](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Scala-Jonas-Boner) - This video shows off all kinds of things that would make a Java developer drool.

[Programming In Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531601) - This is simply a great general-purpose programming book. In addition to being a gentle, clear introduction to the language, it's also a fantastic introduction to functional programming concepts and language design. Even if you hate Scala, 
this book will make you a better programmer.

[Scala For Java Refugees](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/roundup-scala-for-java-refugees) - Very well-written mostly gentle introduction to major Scala concepts.

[Another tour of Scala](http://www.naildrivin5.com/scalatour) - A Java-centric breakdown of fundamental Scala features.

Answer (score 5):

i went to this talk, it was excellent.  can't tell if it is still there due to our internet restrictions, if it's not i'll delete this post.
http://powerhost.powerstream.net/008/00102/100203Scala.wmv

Comment: This is a great talk - where/when was it given?

Comment: at the CME Group, a friend of mine coordinated it.  Venkat Subramaniam has books and other materials.

Comment: Had some issues with the stream loaded by the `wmv` file, but it's also on YouTube at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH75sJAR0hc

Comment: much newer video, a lot of the same concepts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grvvKURwGNg

Answer (score 3):

I'd go straight to the horse's mouth, the Scala website itself: [Code Examples](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/219).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.escalatesoft.com/screencasts

> Escalate software is in the process of creating a series of screencasts for Scala information sharing and training purposes. The first available screencasts are provided here for free and cover the new features of Scala 2.8. In the longer term we will create training materials in the form of these videos along with supporting material that will be for sale from this and other sources as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.jaoo.dk/2009/03/09/an-introduction-to-the-scala-programming-language-by-bill-venners/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following presentation by Jonas Bonér (a well known figure in the Scala community, responsible for the AKKA actors concurrency framework). I'm sure this will whet the appetite for Scala.

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Scala-Jonas-Boner

Answer (score 0):

german introduction, maybe useful for you: http://www.rheinjug.de/videos/gse.lectures.app/Player.html#Scala

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Chapter 1. Zero to Sixty: Introducing Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html) of the Programming Scala book by Dean Wampler and Alex Payne. The rest of the book is also great. The book is freely available online.

---

### EDIT

I recently bought and read the [Atomic Scala](http://www.atomicscala.com/) book by Bruce Eckel and Dianne Marsh. This is the best book I have read so far for anyone wanting to learn Scala.

Comment: This is a very good book. I bought the mobile version of this title and it has an excellent interface, too.